# How to display a popup message on record update

Tags: update, record

When a user edits the value of a custom field SoM_Status__c on Custom object SoM_Request__c using a standard page in Classic UI and clicks 'Save', I want to pop up a message reminding them that they need to review a few Things. This should not stop functionality, rather call attention to the steps that should have taken place. the box should have an OK option that will move forward with updating the record, and a cancel option that will stop the action.

What is the recommended approach for this?

Thanks.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

The recommended approach is to [vote for this idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l2cPAAQ). In the interim, you can only create validation rules or triggers (via addError), which will actually block the transaction. You could still build in a bypass feature by having a custom field (e.g. a checkbox) that the user needs to check to confirm that they're sure they want to continue.

Comment: Thanks for the help.Yes i tried to create the validation rule, with a new checkbox field to bypass the error message. But i am seeing the Error message in the validation rule has a size limit, Can anyone tell me how to increase the size of the Error message in the validation rule?

Comment: @user52664 You can't increase the size. You have to work with what you have. Again, there's no really good solution at this point, because all we really have are workarounds. Make sure you vote on that idea.